# How to display products from specific tag in shopify?

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-template

How to display products from specific tag "organic" in shopify custom template? Here is my code.

```
{% if customer.tags contains 'organic' %}                    
<div class="product-list product-list--collection"> 
      {%- for product in collections.all.products  limit: product_limit-%}  
              {% for c in product.collections %}
          {% if c.title == collection.title %}
                              {%- render 'product-item' -%}  
            {% endif %}  
            {% endfor %}  
              {% if collection.handle=="all" %}
                           {%- render 'product-item' -%} 
                {% endif %}  
      {%- endfor -%}   
   </div>            
{% else %}
 <div class="product-list product-list--collection 
                                {% if has_filters %}
                                product-list--with-sidebar
                                {% endif %}">
                      {%- for product in collection.products -%}
                                  {%- render 'product-item' -%}
                      {%- endfor -%}   
   </div> 
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
{% for product in collections.all.products %}   
{% if product.tags contains "organic" %} 
 {% include 'product-list-item' %}  
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

it will help in displaying the specific product title ,
Please also check the [API documentation here](https://shopify.dev/api/liquid/objects/customer#customer-tags)

```
{% for tag in customer.tags %}
  {% if tag == 'organic' %}

  {% assign collection = collections[my-collection-handle] %}
  
  {% paginate collection.products by 99 %}
  {% assign products = collection.products %}

  {% if collection.products.size > 0 %}

  {% for product in products %}
    {% for tag in product.tags %}
      {% if product.tag == 'limited_edition' %}
        <p>{{ product.title }}</p>
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
  {% endfor %}

  {% endif %}

  {% endpaginate %}
    
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I would remove the `for tag in...` loop - the OP's `if customer.tags contains ...` is a more performant solution for this particular problem :)